# Why is there a video memory leak when using CopyResource to share texture across ID3D11Devices?

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11, directx-12

- I created two devices A and B, where A is the producer and B is the consumer. The texture is shared between the two through D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX. Now I find that every time B calls CopyResource to copy the shared texture to the local, the video memory will keep increasing. This The problem has troubled me for a long time. I searched github or other code sources, but couldn’t find a solution. My machine is Win10 and Geforce GTX 1060.
- The most streamlined code to reproduce the problem is as follows:

  ```
   #include <dxgi.h>
   #include <d3d11.h>
   #include <atlbase.h>
   #pragma comment(lib, "D3D11.lib")

   #define RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr)    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

   namespace SharedTextureLeakTest
   {
   const UINT32 texture_width = 320;
   const UINT32 texture_height = 240;

   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11Device>          device_1 = nullptr;
   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>   context_1 = nullptr;
   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11Device>          device_2 = nullptr;
   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>   context_2 = nullptr;
   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>       shared_texture_dev1 = nullptr;  //owner by device1
   ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>       dst_texture_dev2 = nullptr; //owner by device2
   HANDLE  shared_handle = nullptr;

   HRESULT CheckEnvironmentValid()
   {
       HRESULT hr = S_OK;

       //Create Device1
       if (!device_1)
       {
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL pFeatureLevel;
           UINT Flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
           hr = ::D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, Flags, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device_1, &pFeatureLevel, &context_1);
           if (FAILED(hr)) 
           {
               device_1 = nullptr;
               return hr;
           }
       }

       //Create Shared Texture
       if (!shared_texture_dev1)
       {
           D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
           desc.ArraySize = 1;
           desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
           desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
           desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
           desc.Width = texture_width;
           desc.Height = texture_height;
           desc.MipLevels = 1;
           desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
           desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX;
           desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
           desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

           hr = device_1->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &shared_texture_dev1);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
       }

       //Get Handle of Shared Texture
       if (!shared_handle)
       {
           ATL::CComPtr<IDXGIResource> dxgi_res;
           hr = shared_texture_dev1->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&dxgi_res);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

           hr = dxgi_res->GetSharedHandle(&shared_handle);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
       }

       //Create Device2
       if (!device_2)
       {
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL pFeatureLevel;
           UINT Flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
           hr = ::D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, Flags, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device_2, &pFeatureLevel, &context_2);
           if (FAILED(hr))
           {
               device_2= nullptr;
               return hr;
           }
       }

       //Create Dst Texture
       if (!dst_texture_dev2)
       {
           D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
           desc.ArraySize = 1;
           desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
           desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
           desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
           desc.Width = texture_width;
           desc.Height = texture_height;
           desc.MipLevels = 1;
           desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
           desc.MiscFlags = 0;
           desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
           desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

           hr = device_2->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &dst_texture_dev2);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
       }

       return hr;
   }

   HRESULT LoopOnceTest()
   {
       HRESULT hr = CheckEnvironmentValid();
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       //Open Shared Texture
       ATL::CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>   shared_texture_dev2;
       hr = device_2->OpenSharedResource(shared_handle, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shared_texture_dev2));
       RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       //Copy
       do
       {
           CComPtr<IDXGIKeyedMutex> km;
           hr = shared_texture_dev2->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIKeyedMutex), (void**)&km);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

           INT64 release_key = 0;
           hr = km->AcquireSync(0, 10);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

           if (hr == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
           {
               context_2->CopyResource(dst_texture_dev2, shared_texture_dev2);
           //  context_2->Flush();
           }

           hr = km->ReleaseSync(0);
           RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

       } while (FALSE);

       return hr;
   }
   }

   void DoTest()
   {
       for(;;)
       {
            SharedTextureLeakTest::LoopOnceTest();
            Sleep(1000);
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: Could be a driver bug

Comment: I think you’re leaking memory not every time B calls CopyResource, but every time you’re calling OpenSharedResource over and over again for the same resource. Try to open the texture only once and see if it helps.

Comment: It is true that caching the same resource will not leak the video memory; because this is only a demo, our actual program sometimes cannot accurately determine the resource lifetime, so the cache design may not be simple and effective, and the key is: Why does the same resource of OpenSharedResource cause leakage?